# Подключение внешней процедуры

Tags: delphi

Не получается подключить внешнюю процедуру в Delphi. В чём ошибка?

**Внешняя процедура**

```
unit Unit4;

interface

type TArray = Array of Integer;

implementation

procedure qSort(var A: TArray; min, max: Integer);
var i, j, supp, tmp: Integer;
begin
supp:=A[max-Round((max-min)/2)];
i:=min; j:=max;
while i<j do
begin
  while A[i]<supp do i:=i+1;
  while A[j]>supp do j:=j-1;
  if i<=j then
    begin
      tmp:=A[i]; A[i]:=A[j]; A[j]:=tmp;
      i:=i+1; j:=j-1;
    end;
end;
  if min<j then qSort(A, min, j);
  if i<max then qSort(A, i, max);
end;
end.
```

**Сама программа**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Grids, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Buttons, XPMan, Unit4;

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
begin
    i := len;
    qSort(d,d[0],d[i-1]);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы никогда, видимо, не задавались вопросом, для чего `unit` разделен на интерфейсную часть и часть реализации?

Все, что объявлено в `interface`, видимо для других модулей. Все, что объявлено **только** в `implementation` видимо только в рамках данного модуля.

Заголовок функции вынесите в `interface` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Выносил, всё работает, если нет **var**. Если есть в процедуре возвращаемое значение, то он пишет что не соответствуют типы.

Comment: Показывайте конкретно, какие данные вы передаете в функцию (что такое `d`) и заголовок функции, соответственно.

Comment: Всё разобрался. Спасибо.

Comment: Если ответ помог, галочку ткните